# Object not complete showing on Layout While on Modeling its shows completely

Tags: modeling, objects

Im kinda lost. Im not sure why on Layout iS just shows Limited section of the object like i was on mask while on Modeling is shows the object completely.

[image]
[image]

Added 3rd Picture

[image]

Heres the File so you could check it out.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ld4AJKD_xWs9actJQT3nvtem_44qFe1l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try Alt+h to show hidden vertices in Edit mode

Comment: No luck bro already did that.

Comment: You should share the file so we can take a look

Comment: I added the file hope you could help me. Thanks

Comment: Found the fix. Press Alt B